# Convert Json to table in Sql Server

Tags: sql, json, t-sql

I have the following Json:

```
{
  "archeTypes": [
    {
      "archeTypeId": 12,
      "elements": [
        {
          "elementId": 6,
          "value": "string6"
        },
        {
          "elementId": 7,
          "value": "string7"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json='{"archeTypes":[{"archeTypeId":12,"elements":[{"elementId":6,"value":"string6"},{"elementId":7,"value":"string7"}]}]}';
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH (
    ArcheTypeId INT '$.archeTypes.archeTypeId',
    ElementId INT '$.archeTypes.elements.elementId',
    Value NVARCHAR(max) '$.archeTypes.elements.value'
    );
```

Here is the table that I want to:

| ArcheTypeId | ElementId | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 6 | string6 |
| 12 | 7 | string7 |

How can I convert the json to table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help? (using `cross apply`)

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json='{"archeTypes":[{"archeTypeId":12,"elements":[{"elementId":6,"value":"string6"},{"elementId":7,"value":"string7"}]}]}';
SELECT archeTypes.ArcheTypeId,elements.ElementId,elements.Value
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH 
        (
            archeTypes nvarchar(max) as JSON
        ) as archeType cross apply
        OPENJSON(archeType.archeTypes)
        WITH
            (
                archeTypeId INT,
                elements nvarchar(max) as JSON
            ) as archeTypes cross apply
            OPENJSON(archeTypes.elements)
            WITH
                (
                    elementId INT,
                    value nvarchar(max)
                ) as elements
    ;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de1ea56560456cf61536414a5307a330)

Answer (score 0):

You can also supply a JSON path to `OPENJSON` in order to jump directly to `archetypes`

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"archeTypes":[{"archeTypeId":12,"elements":[{"elementId":6,"value":"string6"},{"elementId":7,"value":"string7"}]}]}';

SELECT
  at.ArcheTypeId,
  e.ElementId,
  e.Value
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.archeTypes')
  WITH (
    archeTypeId INT,
    elements nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) AS at
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(at.elements)
  WITH (
    elementId INT,
    value nvarchar(100)
) AS e;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a06982cff26e040af10cf251eaa22cb)